# Cycle2 - goto: skipping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

Is there a way in Cycle2 to tell when the `goto` function is being skipped due to it already being on that slide.

I have some cases where it could handle and I want to handle this in a proper way, but I can't seem to find any event that's being triggered for this.

```
$slider.cycle('goto', 0); //[cycle2] goto: skipping, already on slide 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `goto` doesn't fire if you are targeting the current slide. You can see this in the [source code](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js) (line 951 as of this writing):

```
if (num == opts.currSlide) {
    opts.API.log('goto: skipping, already on slide', num);
    return;
}
```

If the license allows it, remove that block from the code and handle the `cycle-before` event that will now be fired (I didn't test it, but I assume it will!). You could also directly implement your logic there or even add a custom event yourself, depending on what you are planning to do.

Comment: Thanks, from what I can see from the license it does allow you to edit the code and use it. I just gave it a quick try and fired a custom event `opts.API.trigger('cycle-slide-skipped', [ opts ]);` and that seems to work just fine.